# Managing top menu entries in Squeak

Tags: menu, smalltalk, squeak

I was trying to open a `Transcript` window from my `Workspace` and I could not find the way to do it.

I trid to solve it myself `Exploring` the `DockingBarMorph` but I was not successful.

My questions then are:

1] What is the expression that gets executed when I press "Tools -> Transcript" ?

2] Can you find that information digging into the DockingBarMorph?

3] If I want to add/modify entries in the Menu or just see what are the functions called what should I do ?

Answer (score 5):

When you want to find out what a menu item is doing behind the scenes:

1. Open the menu in question with the mouse over the menu item in
   question
2. Bring up the halo on it (middle-click twice: the first time gets you
   the halo for the menu, the second time the halo for the specific
   menu item)[image]
3. Click the wrench icon
4. Select the 'explore morph' item[image]
5. In the explorer window, the selector ivar will tell you which method
   gets executed when the menu item is selected (to quickly open a
   browser on it from this window click on the selector ivar and in the
   evaluate pane type 'self browseAllImplementorsOf: self' and doit)[image]

Comment: Aha! I knew Exploring the item in some way should have given me the answer. But I was looking for an ivar with name as `run/execute/doit` and value like `[ do something ]`  . Instead, i see, destination object and message to send are in different ivar! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. `Transcript open` is the expression you are looking for.
2. The `Transcript` menu item has a tooltip that reads `'Open the Transcript'`. If you look for methods with such a String, you will get `TheWorldMainDockingBar>>#transcriptMenuItemOn:`, which shows how to respond to question 1.
3. I would start at `#trasncriptMenuItemOn:` and keep looking for senders until I reach to the point where the menu is built.

I know, my answer to item 2 is not what you asked, but it seems close enough, doesn't it?

Comment: Hi @Leandro, it is a while i am studying your answer. I am going to add some thoughts in another Answer because I will have more formatting freedom there.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is an elaboration on previous answers. It will add nothing new but will make life easier for other Smalltalk/Squeak beginners.

### Search string in methods source code

Usually in books you will find explained how to look for methods using the `Method Finder` which is good if you know either part of the method name or you can write down what the method does.

What @Leandro illustrates is how to look for a method knowning that in its source code definition there is a certain string. Which is very powerful because, as seen, we can look for Ballon strings, but also for comments!

To perform such kind of search in **Squeak 5.2** do:

1. Write the string you want to look for in the `Workspace`
2. Hilight the string
3. RightClick on it -> select `more` at the bottom of the menu -> select `method source with it`

### How to add an entry to the Squeak menu

Following the first comment directions I was able to get where I wanted. That is, to add an entry to the `Tool` menu widget.

I will write here how I did, because sometimes you just want a cookbook answer. But, as a beginner, if you are not in a hurry, try not to read what follows, try to get there yourself.

**CAVEAT**. The procedure is very specific, methods name may change in future. What's here is working for me in **Squeak 5.2**.

1. With your `System Browser` enter the class `TheWorldMainDockingBar`
2. Select protocol `submenu - tools`. modify the method `transcritMenuItemOn` and save a copy named `myTranscriptMenuItemOn`.
3. In the method code change `contents` string to `My-Transcript`.
4. Go to protocol `construction`, method `toolsMenuOn` and

```
        workspaceMenuItemOn: menu;
        transcriptMenuItemOn: menu;
        myTranscriptMenuItemOn: menu;    " *** ADD THIS *** "
```

5. Of course, save when you edit
6. Go to your `Workspace` and run this

```
      TheWorldMainDockingBar updateInstances.
```

7. Visit the `Tool` menu, you should see the new entry `My-Transcript`.

Comment: Good explanation! I would also mention that in some cases (like this one) there is no need to scan the entire source because the `String` we are looking for must be a *literal* in some method. The menu item for this is `method strings with it (E)`, which will only search in the literal frames. This searching criterion is more specific and may be useful in cases where too many methods contain the `String` in their source code and we are only interested in those that have it as a literal.